Mileage table argument in Weinberg's GR
The following sentences are from Weinberg's book on gravitation, where he says that we can use airline distances between four places on earth to tell earth surface is curved. The page number is 7.
Consider $N$ points in a plane. We can use one point as an origin of coordinates and draw an x-axis through a second point, so that the distances between the various points are described in terms of $(2N-3)$ coordinates, that is, the x-coordinates of the second point and the x-and y-coordinates of the remaining $(N-2)$ points. But there are $N(N-1)/2$ different distances between the N points, and thus for large engouh N these distances must be subject to M algebraic relations, where $M = N(N-1)/2-(2N-3)=(N-2)(N-3)/2$
I am having difficulty following his argument.

Why only draw an x-axis? What about the y-axis?
Why is the number of algebraic relations=number of distances-number of unknown coordinates?
Why does N need to be large enough?



Once you draw the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis is automatically fixed. 2) Total number of parameters = X$, Max. number of allowed independent parameters = $Y$. It follows that the number of relations in $X$ must be atleast $X-Y$. 3) Number of algebraic relations is a non-negative integer so the relations exist only if $X \geq Y$.


The book didn't assume we have to use Cartesian coordinates. I am not sure what you mean by parameter. In your words, total parameter=total number of distances. independent parameter=number of unknown coordinates?
